# DNS error when trying to connect to Windows Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azureservicebus

The remote name could not be resolved: 
'x.servicebus.windows.net'.TrackingId:bbfe86f8-b5d3

1. Doing an nslookup works fine.
2. I can hit the url from the browser with no issues.
3. *Usually* rebooting resolves the issue. It seems to be the consistent thing, but sometimes even this doesn't work. Sometimes simply waiting until later fixes the issue.
4. I've tried closing IIS express, resetting my ip, closing visual studio, etc., but nothing immediately resolves it, other than rebooting, but like I said this doesn't always work, so not sure it's even related.
5. I've tried disabling my firewall. I uninstalled norton anti-virus, but no luck. I've also disabled Windows Defender.
6. This only seems to be happen on my Windows 8.1 machine. Even when I'm
   experiencing the error, I can run the same code from my Windows 7
   machine with no problems. I don't use my Windows 7 machine enough
   though to know if it is really a Windows 8 specific issue.

Microsoft mentions possibly using Shared Access Signatures as an alternative for connecting to the service bus, but I'm not looking to rewrite my code over what appears to be a possible bug in Microsoft's SDK. **Does anyone know how to diagnose this? I am wondering if there are trace logs that can be setup in web.config specifically for the servicebus perhaps that might give me some additional error information. Or if someone else has run into this and can provide some insight.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a server issue on Microsoft's end which is why it was impossible to resolve through code and machine changes. It took awhile for them to get it figured out and resolved. If anyone has a similar issue they may want want to consider this possibility as well and get in touch with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem anything specific to the Service Bus APIs, you can get more information on the IP configuration and reset it on you Windows 8.1 box as follows:

Open an administrator command prompt and type the following:

netsh int ip reset

netsh winsock reset

Check if any errors are listed?  If not, go ahead and reboot the computer.

Comment: Microsoft does say this is a bug with the service but I don't think they don't know what causes it. It seems to be related to Windows 8, but I'm not sure. I will give this a try and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it's a coincidence, but so far this is working. Not sure why this is different than a reboot or if I just haven't given it enough time yet, but so far so good. I'll let you know in a few days for sure if it worked as it is random and giving it time is the only way I will know.

Comment: No luck with the reset, although Microsoft is looking into the matter as others are having the same problem. Thanks again.